# The method authorizeRequests() from the type HttpSecurity is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Estoy usando recien Spring Security y me sale este error de que esta obsoleto el metodo, pero no se como cambiarlo o en donde buscar para poder actualizalo.

```java
 
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    
    @Configuration
    public class SpringSeguridadConfiguracion 
    {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http.authorizeRequests() **<<< Aqui es donde me lanza el error.**
            .antMatchers("/","/listar").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/form/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/eliminar/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/editar/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/ver/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()           
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()      
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/error_403");
            return http.build();
            
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el "*http.authorizeRequests()*" lanza este error:  The method authorizeRequests() from the type HttpSecurity is deprecated.

y en el "*.antMatchers*" lanza este otro error: The method antMatchers(String, String) is undefined for the type ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry

Entiendo que el metodo esta obsoleto, pero como lo cambio?, Que uso?, donde busco?

Estoy usando todas estas dependecias

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.JPA.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProyectoK</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProyectoK</name>
    <description>nn</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

La mejor opción siempre será consultar [la documentación](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)). Lo que tiene para decirnos:

> Deprecated. For removal in 7.0. Use authorizeHttpRequests() instead

Básicamente sugiere utilizar la función [`authorizeHttpRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests()). A su vez, esta sobrecarga también está obsoleta y sugiere utilizar [la que recibe un parámetro](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)). Allí mismo se puede encontrar un ejemplo de uso:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
            authorizeHttpRequests
                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
        )
        .formLogin(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```